# Is it possible to "soft code" a file path in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

Please excuse the novice question.

I just started playing around with scripting on Windows. I have a couple of batch files in my D:\ root folder and they have hard-coded links in them to a specific path. I now want to move these batch files out of the root of my D drive and into a special "scripts" folder. But several of my files look for text files that are in my D:\ root - I don't want to go back and have to hard code the path each time I want to move these files.

Is there some sort of magic I can work in the file path so that it looks for that file anywhere on D drive, or am I stuck hard coding and really planning this out?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest one of the following: 1) add a parameter to the script and use it as a path to be used for looking up files (annoying as you always have to add a parameter) or (better) 2) add a variable in the beginning of your script with the path (which you can change if needed) or (best) 3) a combination of 1) and 2) - set up a default path variable and if a parameter is passed use that one.   I would not use a search my whole D drive in the script as your D drive could be really big and filled with data which would take too much time. You could make it "smart" and use multiple locations.

Comment: Or set an environment variable in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can recode the batch files to use relative paths when referencing the files (so instead of, say `D:\Scripts\SomeFile.txt`, just make it say `.\SomeFile.txt`).  When running the script from the command line, you just have to CD into that directory first, and then invoke the script with a fully qualified path (if the script is not in the same folder as the files you're manipulating).

Alternatively, if you want to run the script by double-clicking on an icon from Explorer, create a shortcut to the script, and put the D:\Scripts folder (or whatever) into the Working Directory box of the shortcut's properties.  Both will ensure that `.` evaluates to the "current working directory" regardless of where the script file itself is actually located (although if it's in the same directory, all the better).